# How do I "echo" a variable in a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, echo

I typed in this:

```
:Password1
Echo so, make up a password for your info.
Set /p %password%=
echo OKAY! your password is %password% , right?
echo (Y/N)
```

and it comes out as this:

```
So, make up a password for your info.
(me:) Password
OKAY! your password is , right?
```

I want it to say

```
"OKAY! your passsword is "Password", right?"
```

Comment: Please open a command prompt window, run `set /?` and read the output help. The syntax is `set /P variable=prompt text` or better `set /P "password=Enter your password: "`. And please note that variable `password` keeps its current value if already defined and user hits just RETURN or ENTER. So better insert above password prompt the line `set "password="` to make sure the password variable does not already exist from a previous run. You can also define a very strange default password for testing if the user has entered anything at all.

Answer (score 6):

Your set statement is wrong you should not use % there. It should be

```
set /p password=
```

Answer (score 4):

All you need to do is remove the %% when typing in your set command.
This is what it should be:

```
:Password1
Echo so, make up a password for your info.
Set /p password=
echo OKAY! your password is %password% , right?
echo (Y/N)
```